# Reduce the complexity of a program

Tags: java, time-complexity

How can I reduce the complexity of this code :
this code returns true if there are two elements in the array whose sum equals a number K

```
public static boolean methode(int c, int[] t) {
    for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < t.length; j++)
            if(j != i && t[i] + t[j] == c)
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Iterate through the array with one for-loop and keep _count_ of how many times you find `k`.

Comment: Wait, you said "return true if two values equal k". Do you mean if the **sum** of two values equals k?

Comment: @khelwood I *just* noticed this myself. I didn't get a good look at the code at first but it seems that's indeed the intention - if the *sum* of two elements is `k`, not if two elements individually are equal to `k`.

Comment: @VLAZ Maybe the OP will be considerate enough to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the option, you can use `Set` to store previous numbers. It reduces time complexity from **O(n*n)** to **O(n)**, but at the same time in increases space complexity from **O(1)** to **O(n)**.

```
public static boolean verification(int k, int[] tab) {
    Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        if(unique.contains(k - tab[i]))
            return true;

        unique.add(tab[i]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks first , i just want to know why you use Set to store the values and if can i use Arraylist or Array in tis place thanks

Comment: Because `Set` contains **unique** elements and `contains()` takes **O(1)** time. `ArrayList` will not give you such properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the sum of two elements then you can use the following code. It's a bit simpler:

```
public static boolean verification(int k, int[] tab) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tab.length - 1; i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < tab.length; j++)
            if(tab[i] + tab[j] == k)
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Solution is corerct, but from `big O` perspective, it has **the same** complexity.

Comment: thanks but this code complexity equals the code complexity i put in my question.